# Sequencing api calls in React + Redux + RTKQuery

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I'm having trouble understanding how react / redux / rtkquery is intended to be used. I understand this is probably a stupid question. Unfortunately, other than many references saying this cannot be done in this way, I can't find one that suggests how the desired effect can be achieved. A code snippet for what I would *like* to do is shown below.

Specifically, I'm using an API slice built using rtkQuery.

- One endpoint, `myUserProfile`, gets the user profile for the currently logged in user. This works by itself.
- Another endpoint `userStub`, gets a redacted user profile for any specified user. This also works if I provide a static user_id to the component.

What I want to do is create a component which renders a user profile stub. If the user_id is specified, the profile for that user_id is shown. If it isn't, then I wish to use `myUserProfile` to get the user_id for the currently logging in user.

However, the `myUserProfile` result is not guaranteed to exist in cache at the time this component is being rendered. This means that :

- If the user_id is not specified, then I can't actually call `userStub` since I don't have a valid parameter to give it.
- `myUserProfile` may take some time to retrieve the user profile.
- Because of the conditional rendering, specifically, the check on `profileIsFetching`, I will end up with a different number of hooks in different executions of the component. This is not allowed.

How can I implement conditional API calls / sequencing of API calls to achieve this kind of effect?

```
import React from "react";
import { useMyUserProfileQuery, useUserStubQuery } from "../endpoints/user";


interface UserStubProps {
  user_id?: string;
}


const UserStub: React.FC<UserStubProps> = ({ user_id }) => {
  
  if (!user_id){
      const { data: profile, isFetching : profileIsFetching } = useMyUserProfileQuery();
      if (profileIsFetching){
        return (
          <div> Loading Profile ... </div>
        )
      }
      user_id = profile?.auth0.user_id!;
  }
  
  const { data, isFetching } = useUserStubQuery(user_id);    
  
  if (isFetching){
      return (
        <div>
          Loading ...
        </div>
      );
  }

  return (
      <div>
          <p> Name : {data?.name} </p>
          <p> Nickname : {data?.nickname} </p>
          <p> Picture : <img src={data?.picture.toString()}></img> </p>
          <p> User ID : {data?.user_id} </p>
      </div>
  )
}


export default UserStub;
```

Edit:

I tried creating a Custom Hook and used it as below :

```
export const useCurrentUserId = () => {
    const { data, isLoading, isError } = useMyUserProfileQuery();
    const userId = data?.auth0?.user_id; 
    return { userId, isLoading, isError };
};

const UserStub: React.FC<UserStubProps> = ({ user_id }) => {
  const { userId, isLoading } = useCurrentUserId()
  
  if (!user_id) { user_id = userId; }
  
  // TODO this results in a bad request to the server with null 
  // user_id before the earlier hook completes. 
  const { data, isFetching } = useUserStubQuery(user_id!);    
  
  if (isFetching || isLoading){
      return ( <div> Loading ... </div>);
  }

  return (....)
}
```

This suffers from nearly the same problem, however. useUserStubQuery gets called with null user_id, and this results in a bad request made to the API server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both code cases/examples you are still conditionally calling a React hook which breaks React's Rules of Hooks.

If I'm understanding your question/issue correctly you want to conditionally call the `useMyUserProfileQuery` hook when there is no passed `user_id` prop value and conditionally call the `useUserStubQuery` when there is either a current user's `user_id` property ***or*** a passed `user_id` prop value.

```
import React from "react";
import { useMyUserProfileQuery, useUserStubQuery } from "../endpoints/user";

interface UserStubProps {
  user_id?: string;
}

const UserStub = ({ user_id }: UserStubProps) => {
  const {
    data: profile,
    isFetching: profileIsFetching,
  } = useMyUserProfileQuery(_, { skip: !user_id });

  const stubId = profile?.auth0?.user_id ?? user_id;
  const {
    data,
    isFetching,
  } = useUserStubQuery(stubId, { skip: !stubId });

  if (profileIsFetching) {
    return <div>Loading Profile ...</div>;
  }   
  
  if (isFetching) {
    return (
      <div>
        Loading ...
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Name: {data?.name}</p>
      <p>Nickname: {data?.nickname}</p>
      <p>
        Picture: <img alt="profile src={data?.picture.toString()} />
      </p>
      <p>User ID: {data?.user_id}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserStub;
```

See [Conditional Fetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Skip is what I was missing. I was looking for some mechanism in the component logic, did not think about checking in the endpoint options.